# How Python interprets function?

Tags: python, interpreter

I am curious about how Python interpreter handles function.

The code below will generate an error at the line `print(x)`.

```
def foo():
    print(x)
    x = 1

x = 0
foo()
```

I would assume that if we expand the code, it will be something like below

```
x = 0
print(x)
x = 1
```

I understand the variable scope in Python.

But my real question is, at the line `print(x)`, shouldn't the Python interpreter have no knowledge about the later variable declaration and simply reference the x in the global scope?

Comment: "shouldn't the Python interpreter have no knowledge about the later variable declaration and simply reference the x in the global scope?" No, that is just not correct.

Comment: A variable within a function is local unless declared `global`.

Comment: Whenever you *assign to a variable* in a function, at *compile time*, the variable is marked as local. A variable cannot be both local and global. If you want a variable to be treated as global in a function where it is assigned to, then you need to use a `global` statement. A global statement is not necessary if you simply reference a variable